# Flutter: I got stuck with a problem in Flutter. I think the problem is the card that does not adapt dynamically

Tags: java, android, dart, widget, flutter

I got stuck with a problem in Flutter. I am a beginner and I think it is simple enough to solve. I think the problem is the card that does not adapt dynamically.

I apologize for spelling mistakes but I'm writing with google translator!
The user inserts a subject and a description from an input, when I try to show them on video in the Home Overview.

I am an Italian boy who has been very close to programming in Flutter and I started with this course. You are the only people I can address. I will offer a pizza Margherita to anyone who can solve this "problem";) !!!

The Widget AssegnoCard is simply a widget with dynamic data taken by input.

The error that Android Studio returns me is like this:

> I/flutter (18690): The following assertion was thrown during
>   performResize():
>
> I/flutter (18690): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
>
> I/flutter (18690): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill
>   their container.In this case, a vertical
>
> I/flutter (18690): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical
>   space in which to expand. This situation
>
> I/flutter (18690): typically happens when a scrollable widget is
>   nested inside another scrollable widget.
>
> I/flutter (18690): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable
>   widget there is no need to use a viewport because
>
> I/flutter (18690): there will always be enough vertical space for the
>   children. In this case, consider using a Column
>
> I/flutter (18690): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap"
>   property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
>
> I/flutter (18690): the height of the viewport to the sum of the
>   heights of its children.

The following code concerns the main.dart file, overview and the homework (where the ListView.builder is located). The code in the other files is identical to that of the video course:

```
    //MAIN.DART
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'panoramica.dart';
import './assegno/gestione_assegno.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _assegno = [];

  void _aggiungiAssegno(Map<String, dynamic> assegno) {
    setState(() {
      _assegno.add(assegno);
    });
    print(_assegno);
  }

  void _aggiornaAssegno(int index, Map<String, dynamic> assegno) {
    setState(() {
      _assegno[index] = assegno;
    });
  }

  void _eliminaAssegno(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _assegno.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        buttonColor: Colors.blue,
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: Panoramica(),
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => Panoramica(_assegno),
        '/gestioneassegno': (BuildContext context) => GestioneAssegno(_aggiungiAssegno, _aggiornaAssegno, _eliminaAssegno, _assegno),
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        final List<String> pathElements = settings.name.split('/');
        if (pathElements[0] != '') {
          return null;
        }
        if (pathElements[1] == 'assegno') {
          final int index = int.parse(pathElements[2]);
          return MaterialPageRoute<bool>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Panoramica(
                _assegno[index]['materia'],
            ),
          );
        }
        return null;
      },
      onUnknownRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Panoramica(_assegno ));
      },
    );
  }
}

//OVERVIEW
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './assegno/assegno.dart';
import 'drawer.dart';
// import 'eventi.dart';

class Panoramica extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> assegno;

  Panoramica(this.assegno);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(child: DrawerWidget()),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Panoramica'),
      ),
      body: Assegno(assegno),
      //Eventi()
    );
  }
}

// HOMEWORK
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'assegno_card.dart';

class Assegno extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> assegno;

  Assegno(this.assegno);

  Widget _buildAssegnoList(BuildContext context) {
    Widget assegnoCard;
    if (assegno.length > 0) {
      assegnoCard = ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            AssegnoCard(assegno[index], index),
        itemCount: assegno.length,
      );
    } else {
      assegnoCard = Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Assegno'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.book),
              ),
              Text('Non è inserito nessun assegno, aggiungerne uno'),
              ButtonTheme.bar(
                child: ButtonBar(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Aggiungi assegno'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                            context, '/gestioneassegno');
                      },
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.note_add, color: Colors.blue,)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return assegnoCard;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
            child: _buildAssegnoList(context)
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build` function for Assegno should have a `Flexible` or an `Expanded` widget in it like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(child: Card(child: _buildAssegnoList(context)))
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the card takes all the space in the Scaffold, how can I fix that???? And what is the difference between Flexible and Expanded?

Comment: @Sabatin02 That's a different question. So you should probably open a different question about it. Ideally with images to show what you want instead.